# Adding filed to an existing Django Model

Tags: django

I have a Django Application with the following model.

```
class Machine (models.Model):
    description = models.CharField (max_length=2048)
    place = models.CharField (max_length=1024)
    user = models.ForeignKey (User)
    url = models.CharField (max_length=2048)
    serial_number = models.CharField (max_length=1024,verbose_name="E-Power Serial number")
    request_name = models.CharField (max_length=1024,verbose_name="Request name (Web Module Name)")
    password = models.CharField (max_length=1024,verbose_name="Password name (Web Module Password)")
    kwh_price = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)
    saving_percentage = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField (auto_now_add=True)
    serial_n = models.CharField (max_length=128,verbose_name="GWC Serial number")
    currency = models.CharField (max_length=128)
    load1_percentage = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)    
    load2_percentage = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)
```

If a want to add parameters to the previous model without destroy/delete/waste the database , How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to just add another field with a default or null=True. That will load all models already in the database with the default or a null value.

You could also create an entirely new model with a foreign key or onetoone field with the current model.

Comment: Ok, so i change the model by adding the new fields and then?

Comment: run ./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate if you're working with django 1.7 +

Comment: If you are using older Django version, use South (https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)